# Query para listar a quantidade(count) de registros de uma foreign key

Tags: sql, sql-server, query, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Estou tentando criar uma query que lista a quantidade de vezes que uma foreign key apareceu de outra tabela mas não estou conseguindo.

[image: Aqui está a tabela 1 - pedido]

[image: Aqui está a tabela 2 - restaurante]

Queria contar quantas vezes cada idrestaurante aparece no pedido, após várias tentativas de select com count e inner join não consegui o resultado esperado.

Comment: Mas só com o que mostrou você consegue registrar mais de um restaurante por pedido (supondo que idpedido e idrestaurante sejam chaves primárias de suas respectivas tabelas)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você está querendo saber quantos pedidos foram feitos por cada restaurante, você pode usar um `GROUP BY` para contar:

```
SELECT
  idrestaurantepedido,
  count(distinct idpedido) as qtd_pedidos
FROM pedidos
GROUP BY idrestaurantepedido
```